Artist who projects animations has 2 love interests
There's this guy who's an artist I think or at least has a black marker that he uses a lot. He has two love interests, one blonde and one black haired.
I don't think it's Two Girls and a Guy. I'm looking through the film to see if it has the scenes below and can't seem to find any:

Guy draws a box around one love interest's chest and labels it "merchandise"
Guy and black haired love interest were watching some animation displayed by projector then and then love interest walks up to the screen and then the animation is displayed on her butt. Then the love interest says something like I'm not letting you go. I'm setting you free.
Then guy displays animations on building of blonde love interest

I suspect this was an American film sometime from 1990-2009, probably comedy/drama/romantic

@Paulie_D edited. probably comedy/drama/romantic

Please try to add anything that may help identification What time period was it showing?   Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions  or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
